# Accessing Elements?

Tags: ruby

I defined my own method to access elements as:

```
class Array2
  def [](key)
    if key.kind_of?(Integer)
      @elements[key]
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

If I had previously declared `@elements` as `Array.new`, both the operations:

```
list = Array2.new
# ...
puts list[0]
puts list.[](0)
```

work properly. Why is the first operation acceptable?

Comment: I don't understand the question. By first operation, I assume you mean `puts list[0]`. Why shouldn't that be acceptable?

Comment: Because I defined the [] operator to look like the second operation. I don't understand why there is not "." or why the parameter is in the middle of the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the `list[0]` and `list.[](0)` syntaxes mean the exact same thing. They call the `[]` method with an argument `0` on the `list` object.

Comment: But why is there no "." in list[0] considering I defined it to as a method and why is the parameter allowed to be between the brackets?

Comment: @BhubhuHbuhdbus, that's [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Every time Ruby sees `object[...]` it calls `object.[](...)` instead.